# Ruby: Unable to start worker - check_for_activated_spec

Tags: ruby, bundler, sidekiq

I am unable to run some of my jobs in sidekiq. And it seems to be somehow related to Bundler.. Maybe.

when I run my puma server with `pumactl start` in the logs I am getting:

```
[156149] ! Unable to start worker
[156149] /home/todd/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.25/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:309:in `check_for_activated_spec!'
```

Currently I'm on `sidekiq 6.5.6` and Bundler `2.3.25`

Anyone know of any issues with those two versions or anything else that may be causing this?

EDIT:
The interesting thing is when I start puma with `bundle exec pumactl start` I get a totally different error:

```
[ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization::DefaultResponseApp] Blocked host:
```

But my host is defined in my `development.rb` file.. in fact I've added the following, so NO hosts should be blocked:

```
  config.hosts << /.*\.ngrok\.io/
  config.hosts.clear
```

Then finally if I just start puma with a `rails s` all is fine, just my sidekiq worker won't run correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that you want to start using Rails and one day you follow the general installation instructions which say that you should run this command:

```bash
gem install rails
```

And you get this output:

```bash
...
Successfully installed rails-7.0.1
```

You also start working with puma and sidekiq and install those gems for the convenience of running `pumactl start` and `sidekiq`:

```bash
gem install puma
...
Successfully installed puma-5.6.2
```

```bash
gem install sidekiq
...
Successfully installed sidekiq-6.4.2
```

Then after a day or a week or a month of tinkering you create a new Rails app:

```bash
rails new app
```

And since you want to use Sidekiq you add that to your `Gemfile`, which looks something like this:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem "puma", "~> 5.6.2"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.1"
gem "sidekiq", "~> 6.0"
```

But you know that there are newer versions of those gems so you update your `Gemfile` to look like this:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem "puma", "~> 6.0.0"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4"
gem "sidekiq", "~> 7.0"
```

And then you run `bundle install` and the gems update. Or maybe you don't change the versions, but some day run `bundle update` which uses the `~>` versioning operator and updates the gems to newer versions.

**Here's where you're going to start running into compatibility problems.**

First problem:

1. When you installed the sidekiq and puma and rails gems to run their scripts like `pumactl` they were installed using `gem install ...` which installed them globally and with a specific version.
2. When you added them to your Rails app and updated the versions they were installed separately by bundler with specific versions that are noted in `Gemfile.lock`.
3. Now your global version of puma is 5.6.2 and your bundled version of puma is 6.0.0.

Trying to manage puma using an old version of the CLI with a new version of the gem isn't guaranteed to work and can introduce hard-to-pinpoint problems. The same is true of the rails and sidekiq gems and any gem with a CLI.

Second problem:

1. When you run scripts like `pumactl` they aren't necessarily going to look at your application's `Gemfile.lock` and they aren't guaranteed to see or respect bundler's configuration for your Rails app when it loads it.
2. When you run scripts prefixed with `bundle exec` (like `bundle exec sidekiq`) it uses bundler to look at your bundled environment and ensure that all the dependencies are properly loaded.

Trying to run a bundled application without `bundle exec` can introduce hard-to-pinpoint problems. The same is true for any gems that have CLI tools.

**Short answer**

Always use `bundle exec ...` to run gem CLIs in your app, whether it's `bundle exec rails server` or `bundle exec puma` or `bundle exec sidekiq`. This will ensure that your app is started or managed using the *bundled gem* rather than the global version.

If you see errors when starting your app using `bundle exec ...` then *pay attention to them* because they are indicative of actual problems that need to be addressed. Likewise, if you *do* see errors with `bundle exec` but *don't* see errors when starting your app using globally installed gems then *pay attention to them* because it means your app is not portable -- it's likely that it is papering over bugs to make the app run and that your app will *not* run on another computer.

**Extended answer**

- `pumactl start` gives you an error -- probably because you aren't using `bundle exec`.
- `bundle exec pumactl start` gives you a different error -- possibly because you're bypassing the standard way to start Rails; `pumactl` will read `configu.ru` and `config/puma.rb` and decide how it wants to start Rails. Use `bundle exec rails server` instead.
- `rails s` doesn't load your sidekiq worker -- because that starts Rails, not Sidekiq, and Rails doesn't run the workers, Sidekiq does. Start Rails with `bundle exec rails s` and start Sidekiq with `bundle exec sidekiq` -- only the latter will run your workers.

Because the errors that you're reporting are due to a misconfiguration of your system and app, I can't give you any more detailed answers. You need to fix your configuration first and determine which of the three different errors you're experiencing is valid.